# SELECT STATEMENT IN A CASE STEMENT INSIDE A SELECT STATEMENT

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

I am trying to display a field value based on the value of field and then find a external table record.

can I do it?

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN (dsp_notes IS NOT NULL) THEN '*'
    WHEN (dsp_notes IS NULL) THEN ''
    ELSE ''
END,
CASE
    WHEN (dsp_priority = '1') THEN [SELECT uvi_value FROM PUB.universalinfo WHERE uvi_key = 'DSP01SHORT']
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you supply sample data from each table and desired results?  This is not the correct usage of `case`.

Comment: Please edit the title to avoid all caps.

Comment: Yes, you can, but the subquery must be enclosed within () brackets, not [].

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is called a scalar subquery and it needs to return one column and one row:

```
(CASE WHEN dsp_priority = '1'
      THEN (SELECT ui.uvi_value FROM PUB.universalinfo ui WHERE ui.uvi_key = 'DSP01SHORT')
 END) as NewCol
```

I strongly encourage you to use table aliases on your column references.